# how to convert long long into NSnumber?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsnumber

```
long long mServerDurationTime = (_mExpTime.longValue) - (serverTime.longValue);
long long curTime = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970] * 1000;
NSNumber newDeviceTime  = (curTime + mServerDurationTime);
```

I want newDeviceTime to be saved as NSNumber.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
long long mServerDurationTime = (_mExpTime.longValue) - (serverTime.longValue);
long long curTime = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970] * 1000;
NSNumber* newDeviceTime  = @(curTime + mServerDurationTime);
```

You can convert from long long, int, CGFloat,... to NSNumber by a very easy way like this:

`NSNumber* number = @(YOUR_NUMBER);`

Answer (score 1):

You could try

```
NSNumber * numberValue = [NSNumber numberWithUnsignedLongLong:(curTime + mServerDurationTime)];
```